# Login with LinkedIn issue

Tags: authentication

I setup an app so we can use Login with LinkedIn. I believe we setup the app correctly, however it's not working. Not sure why.

Attached is a screenshot of our account and settings, and a screenshot of the message we receive. Can you assist?

Here is a link to the page where we want our users to be able to Login with LinkedIn:

https://joplin.ai/signup

Attached is a screenshot of our account and settings, and a screenshot of the message we receive. Can anyone assist?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB6d6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AbrN.png)

We entered the Client ID and Client Secret into our website.

We went through and were able to setup the Google and Facebook versions, but the Login with LinkedIn is giving us issues.